# How to add an empty row to a datatable based on value from column

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I am working with C# 4.5 on a Winform.  I have a DataSet filled with data from my SQL proc that uses a GROUP BY GROUPING SETS that has a row with an aggregate that contains the value "TOTALS" in my second column.  I want to insert an empty row after each row that has "TOTALS" in that column.  This data will be exported to Excel and I want the empty row between groups for legibility.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are creating the excel sheet row by row then you loop through the data table row by row, then insert a blank excel row when ever a row has TOTL.?

Comment: `exported to Excel` - If you are a programmer, you need to control the the "export", and add the line during it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    if (dataTable.Rows[i][0] == "TOTALS")
        dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(dataTable.NewRow(), ++i);
```

Comment: This is not working - it is adding the empty row between the last row in my group and the TOTALS row.  The next group starts in the very next row after the TOTALS row.

Comment: @user1778158, so you dont a programmer. i edited my answer.

Comment: I was trying the code and used i+1 and it worked great.  Thanks!